# Record 2 microphones on one mic-in port (basic consumer audio)

Tags: audio-recording, levels

I am recording sound from two outputs, but one of them is closer than the other, making it a bit louder than the other source. I am recording with a 3.5mm mic-in port on a basic consumer audio card (motherboard).

In order to even out the perceived volume from each mic I was thinking of using a basic audio 3.5mm splitter (1 male to 2 female) into the mic-in port and putting 2 basic microphones (cheap consumer mics), 1 into each 3.5 mm port.

Would this work, or is there a better way to balance volumes from different sources?

Comment: primuspaul - I've edited to bring it on topic. This has slightly changed part of the question, but I hope it still matches what you were aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

A computer mic input is monaural, so you must "mix" two or more microphones together to make a monaural signal. It may be possible to simply parallel two microphones with a "Y-adapter". But even if that works, it does not provide independent control of each microphone loudness.

The conventional solution would be to use an audio mixer which will take several inputs, allow you to independently control the volume of each input, and combine them together into the single output.

Nobody makes a simple and cheap way of doing this with conventional "computer mics" with 3.5mm plugs. At least I have never seen one. It is quite possible to make such a gadget, but when people start using multiple microphones, more conventional gear is used. Like microphones with XLR connectors and mixers with XLR connectors, etc. Although the output of ANY mixer can be sent to your computer. There are even small relatively inexpensive mixers with built-in USB interfaces to connect to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

well i don't really think that the sound card will be harmed, the stakes are really low, there's no pre-amplification or any high current.

On the other hand though i can't even start to imagine how bad of a decision is this , i mean with 100$ you can have 2 decent dynamic microphones + 1 audio card with 2 pre-amps (and 2 channels), i mean the second hand market can get pretty low on these things whatever you are trying to do , really stop scratching your head, pay 100$ and you are fine.